# Django: Static files not being served during deployment

Tags: python, django, server, web-deployment, web-development-server

**So basically I have a Django project stored in a folder called PROJECT** - within that I have 2 folders munbase and MUNbase

munbase contains my settings.py assgi.py wsgi.py and so on and so forth. the settings.py for the same looks something like this:

```
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
# SECURITYWARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'some secret key'

# SECURITYWARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0'] #ip adress redacted for obv reasons


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MUNbase'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'munbase.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'munbase.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

This same folder has a urls.py as:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static # to import static in deployment
from django.conf import settings # to import static in deployment


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("MUNbase.urls"))
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My folder MUNbase (containing most of the actual code) has a urls.py file like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings # to import static in deployment
from django.conf.urls.static import static # to import static in deployment

urlpatterns = [
    #paths demarcated with commas here
    ]
handler404 = 'MUNbase.views.error_404_view'
```

Despite having tried multiple configurations and running **collectstatic** during deployment several times, I am not able to load my static resources, which get saved in a folder such:

```
.../PROJECT/static
```

Any help with fixing this issue would be a great help. just FYI, im using a Linux bitnami server on AWS lightsail

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to host your static files from a s3 bucket, refer [how to server static files from s3 bucket](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/).
- If you don't want to use s3 bucket, you can use whitenoise to serve static files from your own application [see this repo](https://github.com/efi-mk/serverless-django-demo/blob/master/serverless_django/settings.py)
- see the settings file and modify it according to your needs.
- Hope, it helps you. Comment if you have any queries regarding this.

Comment: What if i want to use my own server's static folder within my django project directory to serve static files? I do have a server if I wasn't clear

Comment: Use whitenoise to host static files from your own django project directory. See the settings file of the repo I have specified on how to configure it.That was specified in the second link. I actually deployed my django app in lambda.Go through the settings file and you will get an idea.

Comment: Use whitenoise middleware in django middleware section in settings file and also specify the settings of whitenoise as specified in the settings file.Comment below if you need further help.